# What Google Cloud Platform service supports gRPC out of the box?

Tags: php, laravel, cloud, grpc

Good day everyone! I have deployed a Laravel web application on Google Cloud App Engine Platform but currently, it does not work because it requires a gRPC extension:

```
The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions.
```

I have tried finding a solution but Google App Engine does not seem to support gRPC. Which Google Cloud service supports gRPC? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs)

> Most applications that run inside Cloud Run use HTTP JSON REST to
> serve requests, but that’s not the only protocol it supports; in
> September, it also started to support unary gRPC services.

You can find more details here:

[Not just for HTTP anymore: gRPC comes to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/serve-cloud-run-requests-with-grpc-not-just-http)